# Leaking a string when giving it to object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I am receiving NSCFSting leaks that are traced back to the method below. I am parsing an XML file, and using the strings obtained from textForElement and setting them to variables in an object (EventArticleObject). I know the leaks are not coming from textForElement, as I have no leaks in another parsing method where I am not setting the strings to an object.

The array and dictionary I am filling are not being leaked, it is just the strings. When I goto the Stack Trace and click on one of the leaking strings, this is what shows up:
[image: pic]

The #2 CFRetain is traced back to setLink in the method below, that is what I believe that I am doing something wrong when using objects.

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong here? Thanks a lot!

```
//Parse the weekly events are store. Must first get the date, format it, and attach it to
// the link; this is to get the events for the current week.
- (void)parseWeekEvents
{

TBXML *tbxml;
TBXMLElement *rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *node_channel;
TBXMLElement *node_item;
TBXMLElement *node_traverse;

NSString *fullEventURL;
fullEventURL = @"http://www.millersville.edu/calendar/rss.php?q=&c=&date=";
fullEventURL = [fullEventURL stringByAppendingString:dateURL];
fullEventURL = [fullEventURL stringByAppendingString:@"&mode=week"];

eventsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullEventURL]];
rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

if(rootXMLElement)
{
    node_channel = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"channel" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

    if(node_channel)
    {
        node_item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:node_channel];

        while(node_item)
        {
            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            EventArticleObject *currentEvent = [[[EventArticleObject alloc] init] autorelease];

            NSString *title;
            NSString *link;
            NSString *date;

            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:node_item];
            title = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#38;" withString:@"&"];
            title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#39;" withString:@"'"];

            [currentEvent setTitle:title];

            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"link" parentElement:node_item];
            link = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            [currentEvent setLink:link];

            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"pubDate" parentElement:node_item];
            date = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            NSRange stringRange = {0,16};
            date = [date substringWithRange:stringRange];
            [currentEvent setDate:date];

            if(![datesArray containsObject:date])
            {
                [datesArray addObject:date];
            }

            NSString *eventDate = [currentEvent date];
            NSMutableArray  *temp = [eventsDict objectForKey:eventDate];
            if(!temp)
            {
                temp = [NSMutableArray array];
                [temp addObject:currentEvent];
                [eventsDict setObject:temp forKey:eventDate];
            } else {
                [temp addObject:currentEvent];
            }
            node_item = node_item -> nextSibling;

            [pool drain];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my EventArticleObject.m:

```
@implementation EventArticleObject

@synthesize link, date, title;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title2
           date:(NSString *)date2
           link:(NSString *)link2;
{
    self = [super init];
if(!self)
    return nil;

    [self setLink:link2];
    [self setDate:date2];
    [self setTitle:title2];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I would suggest you throw out `TBXML` in favour of `CWXMLTranslator` from https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation - This way you can replace this error prone XML parser code with two statements and a small three line DSL.

Comment: @PeyolW Thanks for the link! If I can't figure this out I will move on and try CWXMLTranslator.

Comment: Can you also post how the properties are set in EventArticleObject? And if the properties are overridden instead of synthesize, then post those methods. And also where have you released eventsDict and datesArray?

Comment: @Udayakumar Rayala I added the EventArticleObject.m. And I am passing the eventsDict and datesArray to a UITableViewController where they are being set and then released.

Comment: @Udayakumar Rayala I found the porblem! I feel dumb I forgot my dealloc method in my EventArticleClass. I added it and the leaks are all gone; but without you asking for the EventArticleObject code I would had never thought to check that! Thanks a lot!!! I'd accept your answer if you posted "do you have a dealloc method?"

Comment: I guessed it could be the problem with EventArticleObject class. That is why i asked you to post. Anyways, posting the answer you mentioned, up to you to accept or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the EventArticleObject class if all the variables are released properly

Answer (score 1):

Do you release `link` in the `-dealloc` method of `EventArticleObject`?